# A batch PNG processor for windows to pass googles page speed test

Tags: seo

I have googles page speed plugin installed: http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/

It is saying that I have a lot of pngs that aren't compressed on my site.

I tried using the RIOT image optimizer: http://luci.criosweb.ro/riot/

However with attempts using multiple settings I couldn't get it to pass.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: This [article](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/png-vs-jpg) may be relevant to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the suggestions guys. I think in my case the easiest method is to grab the cache files that google page speed produces. Here is the info: http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/using_firefox.html#savefiles

Also you'll need to run it in firefox as chrome doesn't produce the same files.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [`pngcrush`](http://pmt.sourceforge.net/pngcrush/), but presumably you'll get much greater savings from converting to JPEG with quality slightly less than 100 (I usually find 92 pretty good). [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) would be the tool of choice for bulk processing.

I never managed to create paletted PNGs, but in principle those should be pretty efficient when you're dealing with illustrations that only use a few colours.

Comment: No! Don't do that! Do not convert pngs to jpeg! That's horrible advice. Use png for clip art and graphics, and jpeg for photos. They are not interchangeable.

Comment: Well, true, you have to make a decision... I'm just saying. If the OP's PNGs are soo large, then there's a chance they're photographic, non?

Comment: @Ariel: it's a tradeoff. The OP is after speed, converting to jpeg will improve things (marginally).

Comment: @Chris No it won't. Converting to jpeg will make things worse. If you need to reduce file size by sacrificing quality then use http://pngnq.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @Ariel: I repeat: it's a tradeoff. "Worse" is subjective. Jpegs ARE smaller (and therefore faster to download) than pngs. Lossy compression (jpeg) is always going to yield smaller sizes than lossless (png). Such is the nature of lossy compression.

Comment: @Chris that simply isn't true. Some pngs might compress better as jpegs, but most will not. At least not without turning down the quality so low the image becomes visibly fuzzy. pngnq will do a much better job.

Comment: @Ariel: Quantization (which is what pngnq does) will reduce the effective color depth of your image. And a little [googling](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/png-vs-jpg) shows that people don't seem to be too pleased with the results (visually).

Comment: @Chris Yes, I am aware of that article, and it has been roundly bashed. http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1294576 They used a horrible quantization tool which is why the results are so poor. Even gimp does a better job, much less the very good pngnq.

Comment: @Ariel: They mention pngnq by name... just saying.

Answer (score 0):

The good png optimzers are:

- pngout http://advsys.net/ken/utils.htm
- pngcrush http://pmt.sourceforge.net/pngcrush/
- optipng http://optipng.sourceforge.net/
- advpng http://advancemame.sourceforge.net/comp-readme.html

For best results use all 4 in that order.

You can also use pngnq http://pngnq.sourceforge.net/ to reduce the image even more at the cost of some quality. (And after using pngnq, run the image through the optimizers.)

Comment: "All 4 in that order"? Have you noticed a difference between that and just applying the last step?

Comment: @Kerrek Yes. Not for all images, but I've noticed many that get smaller by each step - but only if I do it in that order, if I change the order it doesn't work as well.